# How to write this in one line in bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

How to write this in one line WITHOUT creating extra variables AND duplication of "5"?

```
A=5
B=10
([[ $A == B ]] && echo $A) || echo gt
```

Comment: Why would you want to?

Comment: Why such a requirement ?

Comment: my guess is command line

Comment: @sooqua: You probably made a typo? `$A == $B` instead of `$A == B`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need the parentheses around the bash test and and statement:

```
A=5; B=10; 
[[ $A -lt $B ]] && echo $A || echo "A >= B"
```

If you're upset about bulk, it's harder to make it more simple using bash. But since you are using bash, you have other programs at your disposal, such as python:

```
A=5; B=10;
python -c "print $A if $A < $B else 'A >= B'"
```

Or Perl:

```
A=5; B=10;
perl -le "print $A < $B ? $A : 'A >= B';"
```

Regardless of specific language choice, all are performing a similar task. In this specific case, the perl example is the "lightest". But note that Perl and Python may not be the most portable. If portability is an issue and you don't prefer Bash, consider awk:

```
A=5; B=10;
awk "BEGIN{print $A < $B ? $A : \"A >= B\"}"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
A=5; B=10; ([[ $A == B ]] && echo $A) || echo gt
```

You can separate commands by `;`...

But it's rather unnecessary for most situations. By structuring code, one gets more insight in how it works.

Answer (score 2):

```
echo gt
```

That is just one line, and it introduces no variable.

By the way - what's the use of that?

Comment: I need to limit a number. I thought to do something like this:

A=5
B=10
([[ $A -lt $B ]] && echo $A) || echo "A is greater than B"
But it's too bulky

Comment: Is the number always 5, and is the limit always 10? If not, there must be a way the script knows the number and the limit. In that case, it's most likely that is has them in two variables. What are their names? If you give me the names of the variables, it's quite simple to do the test in one line without introducing additional variables.